# Python Zeep Client to consume Ontario Health EBS MCEDT WSDL(SOAP) webservice

Tags: python, soap, wsdl, soap-client, zeep

I have been trying to use Zeep to generate SOAP envelope for calling a method in the following WSDL:

https://ws.conf.ebs.health.gov.on.ca:1443/EDTService/EDTService?wsdl

So far, I have come up with this:

```
from zeep import Client, xsd
from zeep.transports import Transport
from requests import Session
import urllib3
from zeep.plugins import HistoryPlugin

urllib3.disable_warnings()

session = Session()
session.verify = False
transport = Transport(session=session)

history = HistoryPlugin()
client = Client(wsdl='https://ws.conf.ebs.health.gov.on.ca:1443/EDTService/EDTService?wsdl', 
transport=transport, plugins=[history])

# client.wsdl.dump()

ebsheader = xsd.Element(
    '{http://ebs.health.ontario.ca/}EBS',
    xsd.ComplexType([
       xsd.Attribute(
          'Id',xsd.String()
       ),
       xsd.Element(
           'SoftwareConformanceKey', xsd.String()
       ),
       xsd.Element(
           'AuditId', xsd.String()
       ),
   ])
)
headers = []
headers.append(ebsheader('id-1','software-key-here','unique-id'))

response = client.service.getTypeList(_soapheaders=headers)
```

I am nowhere close to generating an envelope which looks like the samples provided in the API spec.

Being new to SOAP/WSDL, I am having a tough time understanding the super complex API spec http://www.health.gov.on.ca/en/pro/publications/ohip/docs/techspec_ebs.pdf

Has anyone been able to consume this API using Zeep?

Comment: what do you actually want to do? generate the envelope or you want to call the method?

Comment: @Tarique I want to call a method named 'getTypelist' and eventually 'upload'

Comment: If the answer works then please accept the answer Or provide feedback after trying.

Comment: @Tarique I tried called the method using the way you suggested but it results in SSL error

Comment: @ManjyotSingh did you get this implemented using python? If so would you mind sharing the solution?

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the documentation of `zeep` you can see that it makes it very easier to call the soap service methods.

1st of all you need to inspect the wsdl:
`python -mzeep https://ws.conf.ebs.health.gov.on.ca:1443/EDTService/EDTService?wsdl`

then you can see the definition of `getTypelist` in there (considering the first binding):

```
getTypeList(_soapheaders={ebsrequest_header: ns0:ebs_header, msarequest_header: 
ns3:msa_header, idprequest_header: ns2:idp_header}) -> return: ns1:typeListResult
```

so you need to create `ebs_header, msa_header & idp_header`. create a factory for each:

```
factory0 = client.type_factory('ns0')
factory2 = client.type_factory('ns2')
factory3 = client.type_factory('ns3')
```

then create each of these elements:

```
ebs_header = factory0.ebs_header(SoftwareConformanceKey="key", AuditId="id")
print(ebs_header)

msa_header = factory3.msa_header(ServiceUserMUID="muid", UserID="uid")
print(msa_header)

idp_header = factory2.idp_header(ServiceUserMUID="muid")
print(idp_header)

# then create the _soapheaders
headers = {
    'ebsrequest_header' : ebs_header,
    'msarequest_header' : msa_header,
    'idprequest_header' : idp_header
    }

#finally call the method
response = client.service.getTypeList(_soapheaders=headers)

# you can see the sent request from plugin:
print(history.last_sent)
```

note that i tried to run the code but i get connection error.

Hope this helps.